# How to use session id from a previous HTTP request?

Tags: session, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I record my script from internet explorer using JMeter version 3.3 but when I run it the first HTTP request created a new session but the next request is nothing changed it is because the session id of the second request is indicated to its path unlike the first request.

So this is my question, How to use session id from the previous request and put it to the path in the second request. Please see the image below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the first request and configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `SessionId`
   - Regular Expression: `SessionId=([+-]?\d+)`
   - Template: `$1$`
2. Replace hard-coded recorded value in 2nd request with `${SessionId}`

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)